# CIFilter Rotates UIImage in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, cifilter

After applying CIFilter, the UIImage is being rotated 90 degrees. I'm surprised this issue is still happening after so many years. Is there a swift version of these fixes:

Better Fix:
[iOS UIImagePickerController result image orientation after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload)

Original Fix:
[Using CoreImage to filter an image results in image rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8075595/using-coreimage-to-filter-an-image-results-in-image-rotation/8229730#8229730)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image auto-rotates after using CIFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833285/image-auto-rotates-after-using-cifilter)

Answer (score 2):

How about this (where `image` is your `UIImage`):

```
let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)?.imageByApplyingOrientation(imageOrientationToTiffOrientation(image.imageOrientation))

func imageOrientationToTiffOrientation(value: UIImageOrientation) -> Int32
{
    switch (value)
    {
    case UIImageOrientation.Up:
        return 1
    case UIImageOrientation.Down:
        return 3
    case UIImageOrientation.Left:
        return 8
    case UIImageOrientation.Right:
        return 6
    case UIImageOrientation.UpMirrored:
        return 2
    case UIImageOrientation.DownMirrored:
        return 4
    case UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored:
        return 5
    case UIImageOrientation.RightMirrored:
        return 7
    }
}
```

Comment: how does apple let this type of quality into their libraries. I'm amazed!