# CIFilter Auto Rotates image

Tags: swift

CIFilter automatically rotates the image 90 degrees after use.

Is there a swift fix similar to the objective-c fix:

[Image auto-rotates after using CIFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833285/image-auto-rotates-after-using-cifilter)

Is this correct solution to this issue?

Comment: Take the same approach - store the original image's `imageOrientation`, and then pass it to the `UIImage` initializer you're using.

Comment: I have a lot of uses of CIFilter. Are you sure this is the best approach?

Comment: If you're worried about code reuse, you could create a function or extension so you only do it once.

Comment: Thanks. So would this be the correct swift code:

`originalOrientation: UIImageOrientation = imageView.image.imageOrientation;`  `CGFloat originalScale = imageView.image.scale;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had trouble finding resources for swift. I ended up merging 2 examples and using the following code:

```
var angle = 0.0;
if (originImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Right)
{
    angle = 90.0
}
else if (originImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Left)
{
    angle = -90.0
}
else if (originImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Down)
{
    angle = 180
}
else if (originImage.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up)
{
    angle = 0.0
}
filteredImage = filteredImage.imageRotatedByDegrees(CGFloat(angle), flip: false)
```

With this extension:

```
extension UIImage {
public func imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: CGFloat, flip: Bool) -> UIImage {
    let radiansToDegrees: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 * (180.0 / CGFloat(M_PI))
    }
    let degreesToRadians: (CGFloat) -> CGFloat = {
        return $0 / 180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)
    }

    // calculate the size of the rotated view's containing box for our drawing space
    let rotatedViewBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
    let t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadians(degrees));
    rotatedViewBox.transform = t
    let rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size

    // Create the bitmap context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize)
    let bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    // Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width / 2.0, rotatedSize.height / 2.0);

    //   // Rotate the image context
    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, degreesToRadians(degrees));

    // Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    var yFlip: CGFloat

    if(flip){
        yFlip = CGFloat(-1.0)
    } else {
        yFlip = CGFloat(1.0)
    }

    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, yFlip, -1.0)
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-size.width / 2, -size.height / 2, size.width, size.height), CGImage)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
}
```

I am guessing this could be simplified, but it works for me.